# Property 'artist' does not exist on type 'ArtistDetailsComponent'.ype 'ArtistDetailsComponent'

Tags: angular

I can't build my app. When I use 'ng serve' everything is ok, but 'ng build' failed with errors:

> Property 'artist' does not exist on type 'ArtistDetailsComponent'.

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="'./assets/images/' + artist.shortname + '.jpg'" alt="{{artist.name}} photo">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-4">
      <h2 class="mt-3 mt-sm-0 mb-0">{{artist.name}}</h2>
      <h4 class="mt-0">{{artist.reknown}}</h4>
      <p>{{artist.bio}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist-details',
  templateUrl: './artist-details.component.html',
  inputs: ['artist']
})
export class ArtistDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How can I fix it?
More code here: [code](https://github.com/ekater1na/ng-learn-angular-ld)

Comment: Why aren’t you using @Input() and specifying the appropriate type? https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Use `@Input` rather than the `inputs` metadata property. [See here](https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-12). If you insist on using `inputs` metadata properties, then you need a backing variable of the same name in the class. The link shows a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Add a backing variable of the same name to the class. In addition also used type `any` for that backing variable. as below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist-details',
  templateUrl: './artist-details.component.html',
  inputs: ['artist']
})
export class ArtistDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  artist!: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist-details',
  templateUrl: './artist-details.component.html'
})
export class ArtistDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  // If the Artiste type exists and don't forget to import it
  @Input() artiste: Artiste;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```